# Selecting variables that are in a vector with a substitution string in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(kgs_chicken = c(0,1,2,1,2,3,0,1,2,8),
                 kgs_total = c(2,4,8,2,3,4,2,4,6,20),
                 price = c(0.81, 1.42, 2.85, 0.73, 1.07, 
                           1.52, 0.72, 1.42, 1.94, 7.44))
```

And I applied some transformations:

```
df_trans <- df %>%
  mutate(ratio = kgs_chicken / kgs_total,
         kgs_chicken_ln = log(kgs_chicken - min(kgs_chicken) + 1),
         kgs_total_ln = log(kgs_total - min(kgs_total) + 1),
         ratio_price_kgs_total = price / kgs_total)
```

Then, after running an algorithm I am recommended to pick up some variables. This algorithm return just the vector with the names of the variables (which are hardcoded here):

```
filter_vector <- c("kgs_chicken_ln", "kgs_total")
```

Ok, I want to select only the variables applying that vector, but if one of the elements of the vector has a "_ln" string, I want the variable without the "_ln". I have tried this:

```
df %>%
  select(across(ends_with("_ln"), .fns = function (x) gsub("_ln","",names(x))))
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
```

The expected result is:

```
   kgs_chicken kgs_total
1            0         2
2            1         4
3            2         8
4            1         2
5            2         3
6            3         4
7            0         2
8            1         4
9            2         6
10           8        20
```

Consider that I have a dataset with hundreds of variables so a solution could help me to automate that selection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're just selecting the first two original columns, is that intended?

Comment: Where you wrote `c("kgs_chicken_ln, kgs_total")`, I presume you meant `c("kgs_chicken_ln", "kgs_total")` to represent two of your column names. It doesn't look like you use this, but FYI.

Comment: Hello @JonSpring, as I mentioned an algorithm recommends to select those variables. But I want the variable without the "_ln" name. My original dataset has many variables with that log transformation, and the selection depends on the vector resulting from applying an algorithm.

Comment: @Alexis does my code work?

Comment: Hello @KarthikS, as you can see in my expected output the vectors are integers, but your solution gives back a column of doubles which are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove `_ln` string from the vector and select the column.

```
df[sub('_ln$', '', filter_vector)]

#   kgs_chicken kgs_total
#1            0         2
#2            1         4
#3            2         8
#4            1         2
#5            2         3
#6            3         4
#7            0         2
#8            1         4
#9            2         6
#10           8        20
```

In `dplyr`, you can use it within `select` -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(sub('_ln$', '', filter_vector))
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to recover, the original value without the log transformation. Thank you @Ronak Shah

Answer (score 1):

Will this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df_trans %>% select(filter_vector) %>% 
       rename_at(vars(ends_with('_ln')), ~ str_remove(., '_ln'))
   kgs_chicken kgs_total
1    0.0000000         2
2    0.6931472         4
3    1.0986123         8
4    0.6931472         2
5    1.0986123         3
6    1.3862944         4
7    0.0000000         2
8    0.6931472         4
9    1.0986123         6
10   2.1972246        20
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   select(starts_with(trimws(filter_vector, whitespace = "_.*")))
   kgs_chicken kgs_total
1            0         2
2            1         4
3            2         8
4            1         2
5            2         3
6            3         4
7            0         2
8            1         4
9            2         6
10           8        20
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun for your answer, now I have learned that I can use a literal string inside starts_with (which has a vector conversion inside).